# Populating count of records from other collection with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 Mongoose models, Book and Users. i want to do that: When find a book, i want to get the count of current book users.

this is book model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Users = require('../users');
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    book_name: String,
    book_publisher: String
});
var book = mongoose.model('book', schema);
module.exports = book;
```

this is users model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Book = require('../book');
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_name: String,
    book_id: String
});
var users = mongoose.model('users', schema);
module.exports = users;
```

i fetch a book like this:

```
Book.find({book_name:name).exec(
        function(err, book) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            var new_book = book;
        }
);
```

right now tis code fetch a book, but i want to populate count of users inside Users model and add them to the new fetched book object.

i read this document but i can't accomplish that:
[Population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: if you only need the count, without the actual documents, why don't you add a another field in the schema something like this: `users_count: Number`, and update it every time a new user uses the book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User = new mongoose.Schema({
 //existing user properties
 owned_books: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'book'}]
}}
var users = mongoose.model('users', User);

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  book_name: String,
  book_publisher: String,
  owner_ids: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users'}]
});
var book = mongoose.model('book', schema);
```

You'll need to update both schema when you add people to books or books to people. To get the current book users, just find the book and then get length of it's owner_ids field.

Comment: thanks. you know, my main problem is that when i use find method to fetch an specific books, at the same query, get the owner_ids length. in fact i want that the result document has a field contains length of owner_ids. can you show me this with an example? right now what is in my min is that after fetching books, i have to put a loop and for each result document calculate length of owner_ids and replace with its main data. but i is very expensive and strange way. can you help me for a better way?

Comment: You can't do this at the same time using find. Mongo just doesn't have the capability. 

You can use the mongo aggregate framework to find the length of the array. However, it requires a separate query and it is not a fast query. 

You can build that query using
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum

Comment: then you say i have to fetch the result normally and store them in an object, then run aggregation framework and make changes. two steps. is this efficient? i think my database will be on heavy load.

Comment: So as far as I know there are two ways to get the length of an array in a mongo document. 

1. Get the document and in memory check the length.
2. Get the document excluding the array field, then do a separate query using the aggregation framework to match the documents you want, unwind the array, project a count of 1 onto each new row, sum the counts and maybe group by the model id if that is what you want. 

Mongo is really bad at relational type data. If you have the option not to use it I highly recommend using anything else.

Comment: you know, i dont need that array to populate and fetch their data, i just need count. If i write a forEach loop and for each document calculate lenght and then replace it with all array, it can be faster than aggregation method?

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm new to this things, you saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is usually known as reverse lookup. Luckily, someone has already created a module for that. It doesn't seem like its a very commonly used module, but you could see if it fits your needs: [reverse-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-reverse-populate).