# How mongoose population works

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use `Mongoose` `Population` and fetch some information from other collections. My models are:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Users = require('../users');
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    book_name: String,
    book_publisher: String
});
var book = mongoose.model('book', schema);
module.exports = book;
```

And

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Book = require('../book');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_name: String,
    books: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Book' }]
});
var users = mongoose.model('users', schema);
module.exports = users;
```

I want to store each user books inside `books field` and populate them from `Books collection`. But i cant understand, How this connection happens? How my `Users` schema connects to `Book` schema? I mean, _id field inside book schema should be  the same  with _id in users schema? i didn't specify any relation i think but in every tutorial i read, all of them are like this. I want populate each user books separately but what is the key item for comparing in two collection? have i do something in find method? this is my find:

```
Users.find({book_name:name).populate('books').exec(
        function(err, users) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            var new_user = users;
        }
);
```

in fact my question is, how that `.populate('books')` works. I never say which field in books schema related to users schema. i'm confused.

And right now when i run this, I get nothing in populated field, it's empty. should i write a save method and saved items must be under this relation? in my App, this two collection filled separately and from separate sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The populate function works like this, you specify in the schema that the field(in this case books) is an ObjectId and it's ref is the model 'Book', when you populate, mongoose goes to the Book collection and searches for the model with the Id of the book you specified in User, so he converts the field do a Book field instead of the ObjectId.

To see why your code does not work i need to know how you're creating the objects aswell, but with a quick glance i think this may be causing because you specify the model name as 'book' and used in the ref 'Book', i believe mongoose is case-sensitive.

Comment: then _id's in book schema can be duplicate? because i want a user can has more than one books!

Answer (score 1):

The _id in your Books collection should be unique (no duplicates). And on your books array on User schema you should store the books _id's. Mongoose will use those _ids to do the population.

Comment: but how it can distinguish which book belong's to specific user?

Comment: If I understand correctly, one user can have many books and one book can belong to multiple users, right? So it's a many-to-many relationship. There are several ways to model a many-to-many relationships with MongoDB. You have to choose based on what types of queries you'll be doing. I recommend you to read this: http://blog.markstarkman.com/blog/2011/09/15/mongodb-many-to-many-relationship-data-modeling/

Comment: yes you're correct, but for this i found nothing on the web. i cant understand if each book has unique _id, how i can find out each book belong to which user. i read a lot but i can't find out.

Comment: One options to look on the Users collection for the book id, this way you'll find out which User has that book.

Comment: but users collection doesn't store books belong to each user. it should be populated at runtime and saved into books field. isn't it? look at my code above please. i'm confused. where i misunderstood?

Comment: oh my god! it's over one week i'm on this problem and i was thinking it is just a relation and at runtime and after population that books array will be filled!! it's my fault but documentation and resources on the web about this is so poor!! anyway, thank you my friend. i have another question, if you want you can look at it, any suggestions should save my time my friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584142/populating-count-of-records-from-other-collection-with-mongoose