# fetching data from other collections inside Mongoose find method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a App with Node.js and mongoose(mongodb). Is there any way to fetch information from other collections inside find method except `model population`? `population` works with `_id` and my id's in the other collection cant be duplicate and i cant have one to many relation.

For example every user has more than one books. in the books schema `_id`'s should be duplicate and a bunch of them has the same user id. But i don't want this. i want to compare other field.

I read `document#population` in Mongoose documentation but i can't understand:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate

i can't believe for this simple need, Mongoose doesn't have a good api.

this is my schema's:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Users = require('../users');
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    book_name: String,
    book_publisher: String
});
var book = mongoose.model('book', schema);
module.exports = book;
```

And

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Book = require('../book');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        user_name: String,
        books: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Book' }]
    });
    var users = mongoose.model('users', schema);
    module.exports = users;
```

Comment: Can you post your schemas?

Comment: @RodrigoReis: i updated my question. my problem is that books belongs to each user  should have the same user _id? _id can be duplicate?

Comment: I'm already helping you on the other question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, the problem is not with mongoose but mongo. What you're trying to do is basically pull relational data in a non-relational database. From experience I suggest not doing this. If you can't avoid it, use postgres. Postgres supports json data.

In mongoose you can load first level relations (users -> posts) using the .populate method. If you want to pull in a second level relation (users -> posts -> replies), then you end up needing to manually create joins in code. 
  So if a user has multiple books, you can setup your schemas like this.

```
   User = new mongoose.Schema({
     //existing user properties
     owned_books: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'book'}]
   }}

    //now you can query users and populate their books by doing
    Users.find().populate('owned_books').exec(callback)
```

Edit: It could go the other way around, where the book has a collection of users. In any case, _id needs to be unique in a table, but as a field of another document it does not need to be unique, unless you've put an index on that field.

Comment: you know, i just want to fetch some information from other collections inside find method. right now my problem is that books belongs to each user should have the same user _id? _id can be duplicate?

Comment: Edited with an example you might find useful.

Comment: thank you, but i have a question. i think i found out why i'm confused. question is: when i save new book for user, i have to save in two places, one is it's own collection and other is owned_books array of that user. right?

Comment: :oh my god!  it's over one week i'm on this problem and i was thinking it is just a relation and at runtime and after population that owned_books will be filled!! it's my fault but documentation and resources on the web about this is so poor!! anyway, thank you my friend. i have another question, if you want you can look at it, any suggestions should save my time my friend: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584142/populating-count-of-records-from-other-collection-with-mongoose